# ¿Cómo evitar que mi antivirus borre los ejecutables de Delphi? ¿Cómo evitarlo?

Tags: delphi, pascal

### *Hola a todos.*

Actualmente cuento con una problemática que es bastante fastidiosa, mi antivirus (McAfee LiveSafe) esta interfiriendo con delphi (version 10.4), me borra los ejecutables de mis aplicaciones de consola, haciendo que no pueda ejecutarlos. Anteriormente, solamente tenia que cerrar el programa o provocar un cambio en el código, para que se creara otro ejecutable y correr el programa. Pero el antivirus empezó a borrarlos mas rápido de como lo así antes.

Por favor, necesito que me ayuden a resolver este problema que es bastante agobiante, para evitar que el antivirus me borres los ejecutables.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, te recomiendo desactivar todos los permisos de mcaffe cuando necesites realizar dicho ejecutable, así como también te recomiendo desactivar la seguridad de windows.

Abre el software de McAfee.
Haz clic en Seguridad para el PC o en el icono de rueda dentada en la esquina superior derecha.
Haz clic en Firewall.
Haz clic en Desactivar. NOTA: Puede configurar el firewall para que se vuelva a activar automáticamente al cabo de un tiempo predefinido.

Comment: De esa manera es que lo estoy haciendo actualmente, pero necesito una mejor solución que no tenga que ver con desactivarlo. Metras que hacer que el antivirus ignore el ejecutable, no es posible debido a que al correrlo lo detecta como un virus que luego eliminara.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás trabajando a **nivel local** y mientras haces compilaciones de desarrollo (debug) lo más sencillo es que añadas excepciones al antivirus. Ya sea para un determinado directorio o árbol de directorios.

En cuando a **la distribución en clientes**, la mayoría de problemas con este y otros antivirus se eliminan firmando los ejecutables.

Comment: Estoy trabajando local, debido a que soy básicamente un novato en delphi, pero cuento con algo de experiencia de programación ( C#, C++ y Python). Así que no se que es la distribución en cliente. Necesito alguna forma de resolver este problema sin la necesidad de desactivar el antivirus.

Comment: En mi caso no digo que lo desactives, sino que añadas excepciones, además de enviar esos ejecutables a la casa del Antivirus para que los analize y marque como falsos positivos.